How to display all azure blobs with the attached azure front door
I have a blobs in storage container which is having a list of blobs.

Now I want to share it with my front door url with users where they will be able to see all the blobs allowing them to download.
but I can attach only one at a time how to show the entire list in url

create a azure function, call all the blobs and return them, you can also assign a custom domain, so you wouldn't need azure front door if this is the other url the front door is using


How to display all azure blobs with the attached azure front door

To display all Azure blobs within an Azure container using the Azure Front Door URL, follow the steps below.

Create a storage account with a container and blobs.

Once you've created the storage account, navigate to Security + Networking, select Front Door and CDN, and provide the required details




Once you've created the Front Door, you can try accessing the container using the Front Door URL.

<Endpoint hostname>/<container_name>?restype=container&comp=list

For accessing a specific blob, use the following URL format.
<Endpoint-hostname>/<container_name>/<_BlobName_>

Here is my endpoint url for accessing container
venkatendpoint-fvbgf6dwbpe8ccdk.a03.azurefd.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list
After completing all the configurations, when I try to access the Azure Front Door URL, I am able to list all the blobs inside the Azure container.

Here are all the blobs in my container

Reference:
Integrate an Azure Storage account with Azure Front Door
List Blobs

@Saikumar, I hope this helps to resolve your problem? let me know if still facing any issue.
